# Minecraft modding gives a Missingtexture error

Tags: java, eclipse, module, textures, minecraft

I'm trying to make a GUI mod for Minecraft using MCP 6.2 and Eclipse. The GUI (so far)
consists of the `drawDefaultBackground` and a textured rectangle. The problem is that whenever I try out the mod, the textured rectangle is white and says `MISSINGTEXTURE`. I tried redirecting to a default texture like the /gui/furnace.png and it works normally. Any newly added textures give this problem, even if I copy an existing texture with a new name.

**The texture I want to display is in the following directory in the MCP file:**

mcp\jars\minecraft.jar\bliskcraft\BCGUI.png

This is the texture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vktv5.png

and finally my code:

**mod_BliskCraftGui.java:**

*Code removed*

**BliskCraftGui.java:**

*Code removed*

If anyone knows how to check if the player is playing online or single-player, and if online, which server, please add that to your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out that I should put the resources in the `/mcp/eclipse/bin/client/` and the `/mcp/bin/minecraft/` folders.

Answer (score 0):

When using the [Minecraft Coder Pack (MCP)](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de) with the workspace it provides in an `eclipse` directory, the `eclipse\Client\bin` directory is added to the classpath when Minecraft is run from the default "Client" run configuration. This means assets can be placed in the `assets\minecraft` directory beneath that. E.g. to add a texture for a block, the texture PNG can be placed in:

```
MCP\eclipse\Client\bin\assets\minecraft\textures\blocks
```